# Grid View Styling Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

i want to style the grid view like i have to show 4 orders on the grid view in which 2 order has status true and 2 order has status false now i want to apply style like those order have false status should visible in yellow color and those orders are true should visible in normal color like black  here is my grid view

```
<asp:GridView ID="CateringGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="Id">
                    <RowStyle CssClass="GridRow" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("FirstName") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("LastName") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Company Name">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("CompanyName") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Email") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Phone">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Phone") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="People Attending">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("PeopleAttending") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Event Type">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("TypeOfEvent") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Event Date">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("DateOfEvent") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

and my code behind file is

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                this.FillCateringGrid();
            }
        }

        private void FillCateringGrid()
        {
            using (CateringOrderDataContext dataContext = new CateringOrderDataContext())
            {
                var query = dataContext.Caterings
                                       .Where(e => e.Status == true)
                                       .Select(e => e);
                this.CateringGridView.DataSource = query;
                this.CateringGridView.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<RowStyle CssClass='<%=((Catering)Container.DataItem).Status ? "A" : "B"%>' />
```

Where A and B are class names based on whether the Status is true or false. then you can define the CSS format for `td.A` and `td.B`.

Comment: i am not understanding what are u trying to say i just copy paste your code and its giving me error Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event. System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableItemStyle does not have a DataBinding event.

Comment: try changing the # to =. if that doesn't work then search the web for the exception/message and try to debug it.